# How to use multi-GPU training with Python using Caffe (pycaffe)?

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

I saw that recently a [new commit](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/4563) was inserted to Caffe, that should enable multi-GPU training with Python interface/Python custom layers.
I can't seem to train a network using multiple-GPU from my Python code.
I cloned the updated repository and built Caffe with USE_NCCL on.
The commands I tried to use in my Python script:

```
caffe.set_mode_gpu()
caffe.set_solver_count(2)
```

The error I get:

> F0223 10:27:41.249380 23468 python_layer.hpp:25] PythonLayer does not
>   support CLI Multi-GPU, use train.py

When running the script from the command line, it simply uses 1 GPU only.

Comment: Can you gain training speed up with caffe multi-gpu?

Comment: Yes you can gain speed-up

Comment: How much speedup did you gain? I tested on AlexNet with NCCL, achieved 1.92 speedup with 2 cards, but 1.72 with 4 cards. Without NCCL, it's 1.40(2 cards) vs 1.33 (4 cards).

Answer (score 3):

I also recently tried the multi GPU support in Python Caffe. You might want to give this a read:
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/docs/multigpu.md

Caffe only supports multi-GPU from command line and only during TRAIN i.e you have to use the train.py file (./build/tools/caffe train) and give the GPU's you want to use as arguments to this script. 
It is pretty well explained in the file I pointed you above.

I tried to use the caffe.set_solver.count(2) in my python script as well. I didn't get any error however my model trains only on one GPU.

-Ayushi

Comment: as this answer is quite old, can we assume now one can take advantage of multiple gpus in `TEST` phase now?  `caffe.set_device([0,1,2,3]) caffe.set_mode_gpu()`

Comment: You should check for the latest version of Caffe. I am not using Caffe anymore so I can't comment if anything has changed from before.